Collpase_rows middle alignment not working properly
I'm trying to generate a nice table using Rmarkdown to export in pdf, to do so I'm using kable and its formatting options and the function collpase_rows to merge some cells.
Here it's the problem, I'm using the argument valign="middle" but it's not correctly aligning to the middle of the space, "Example1" should be aligned with the number "2" in the second column and it's not.
Do you have any idea how to properly align the collapsed cells?
This is the code I'm using to generate the table:
library(kableExtra)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(A=c(rep("Example1",3),rep("Example2",3)),B=1:6,C=c(1,1,1,2,2,2),D=6:1,E=c(1,1,1,2,2,2))

knitr::kable(data,
             col.names = linebreak(c("","B","C","B", "C"),align = 'c'),
             caption = "Example.",
             format = "latex",
             booktabs = T,
             linesep="\\addlinespace",
             escape = F,
             align = "c") %>% 
  add_header_above(.,c(' '=1,'Ascending'=2,'Descending'=2),
                   bold = T,
                   escape = F) %>%
  collapse_rows(columns = c(1,3,5), valign = "middle") %>%
  kable_styling(font_size = 10,
                latex_options = c("striped", "hold_position"))



The issue are the horizontal lines added by the default latex_hline="full". If that is not important for you, you can set latex_hline="none".

Thanks @stefan, removing the lines solves the problem, but I'd like to know it there's some solution to both keep the lines and have it properly aligned
